# A descriptive geographic statistics, or descriptive arithmetics question

Tags: descriptive-statistics, controlling-for-a-variable, geography

*[Please point me to a more statistical/arithmetical part of stack exchange if there is one.  I can't find it]*

Country A has 16 million inhabitants and 2.000 MW of solar panel generated power, also a GDP of $50.000 per capita

Country B has 160 million inhabitants and  2 MW of solar panel generated power, also a GDP of $10.000 per capita

Would it be correct to say that country A has two thousand times as much solar power because: 
- If country A was as populous as B, they would have 20.000 MW in solar power. 
- But if country A  was as poor as country A, they would have 4.000 MW solar power. 
So, after adjusting for differences in population and wealth, country A still has twice the solar power that country B has?

Is it correct to compare like that, or not?

Follow up question: Is there a formal way, when comparing countries or groups, to adjust for differences in various traits (such as popsize and gdp per capita?)

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  As you might guess, this is a common issue.  It often goes by the phrase "controlling for" a variable in a *regression* context.  This search will point you towards relevant threads with good posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=control+regression+score%3A5+-case.

Comment: I am trying to compare in a straight way, not tainted by anything.